# Understand the meaning of "tall order"

Tags: meaning, metaphors

I was wondering why a "tall order" means a formidable task or requirement?

Is it a metaphor? If so, how shall I understand it?

Answer (score 6):

An *order* is "a direction or commission to make, provide, or furnish something" ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/order)).  *[Tall](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tall)* means "large in amount or degree".

So a *tall order* is a direction to do something considerable.  It's not a metaphor; it just includes a rarer usage of *tall*.

Answer (score 5):

The OED says *tall* also means a large amount, and is originally US slang. Their first quotation is from Charles Dickens' *American Notes for General Circulation* (1842):

> We were a pretty tall time coming that last fifteen mile.

A *tall order* is "something expected to be hard to achieve or fulfil" F. W. L. Adams wrote in *The New Egypt* (1893):

> It's a tall order, but it's worth trying, isn't it?

This kind of demanding request had also been intensified with other adjectives such as *big, large* and *strong*, for example in Anthony Trollope's *The way we live now* (1875):

> By Jove, it's a rather strong order when a girl has just run away with another man. Everybody knows it.

This use of *tall* is also seen in *tall tale*, covered by [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-tal2.htm) who begin:

> *Tall* is one of those curious words, like nice, that has had more meanings down the centuries than you can shake a stick at. Back in Anglo-Saxon times it meant swift or prompt, and later on it variously had senses of fine, handsome, bold, strong, brave, skilful and a good fighter. It was only in the sixteenth century that it started to mean somebody or something physically higher than normal.

Answer (score -3):

The allusion is to any form of work order with constituent elements arranged as line items -- a meal order at a restaurant, for example -- and a large number of such items on it.  The required vertical space makes the order "tall", and the quantity of items makes it a lot of work.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: @Danielδ: Nope, can't be arsed.  I get more than my fill of justifying myself with argument from authority editing Wikipedia; I participate in SE sites on the theory that being right should be enough.

Comment: Well, it makes sense; I just wondered if you made it up.

Comment: @Danielδ: I honestly have no idea; it's just what I seem to have stored at that location in my brain.  I may have read or heard something to that effect, but if so I couldn't tell you where.

Comment: @Chaos "Sounds plausible to me" just doesn't cut it as a conclusive argument. "Sounded plausible to some unknown person who postetd it on Wikipedia" -- now that's conclusive. :-)

Comment: @Jay: Hey, we can do better than that, these days -- we can cite a Wikipedia article that cites a newspaper that got its information, uncredited, from a citationless Wikipedia article!

Comment: Doesn't sound plausible to me, because "tall" is rarely or never used in that way. "Tall" refers to physical objects with a shape, or representations of such. That gets extended to talking about "the tall rectangle" in contradistinction to the fat one, perhaps, but I can't imagine it being used for a list of entries: that would be long, not tall.